# Cycles mist pass does not appear in reflection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: Blender cycles mist reflection problem]

I'm having a problem with reflections of objects in cycles, where the standard mist pass does not seem to be properly reflected. In the image I have uploaded you can see that the mist obscures only the three nearest cubes, but in the horizontal reflective plane many more cubes are visbile going much further back, whereas in reality the visibility should be the same. I've tried switching to volumetric mist but I'm doing a long animation and it takes far longer to render.

here is the setup for the mist pass - very simple and following tutorials

[image: here is the setup for the mist pass - very simple and following tutorials]

Comment: can you show how did you set the mist, reflections?

Comment: [![here is the setup for the mist pass - very simple and following tutorials][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIx61.jpg

Comment: yes, it does the same on my 2.79... can't find a solution, let's see if others find something...

Comment: What about faking mist inside shader using Z-depth for object that needs reflection and use Mist pass for others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mist pass is not going to get the results you are looking for. It will only output the distance from your geometry to the camera and won’t respect your shaders’ reflectiveness.  That’s why it renders so much faster than the right way to get this look, the volumetric shader for the world.

Comment: That's good to know. I guess I'll have to live with the mist pass in this case then.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable `Denoising Data` pass
   [image: Scene > View Layer]
2. Render image out (high number of samples preferred for less aliased result)
3. Go to compositing, use [Map Value](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/vector/map_value.html) or [Normalize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/vector/normalize.html) node on Denoising Depth to get the depth data needed
   [image: Compositing node setup example]

Result:
[image: Left: Composite, Right: True Depth]